# JQuery Mobile: Zoom into a image

Tags: jquery-mobile, zooming

Is there a way using JQuery Mobile 1.0rc2 or any plugins to zoom into an image and at a certain point to load a new page or perform ?

For example: 
I have a product overview and when I zoom an image the related detail page is shown.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can look into http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4